# Canonical form of projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, projection-matrices

I am reading through this paper by [Stewart](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/100792093) on oblique projectors, i.e. matrices $P \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ where $P^2 = P$.
He describes a canonical form for projectors as follows.

> Let $P$ be be a projector of order $n$ and rank $p$. Then there is an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that
> $$
> QPQ^* = 
> \begin{bmatrix}
> I_p & T \\
> 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix},
> $$ where $T$ is a $p \times (n-p)$ diagonal matrix whose entries are the tangents of the canonical angles between the column space of P and the row space of P.

The proof for this form can be found in this paper by [Dokovic](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01818492).

However, I am unable to figure out why $T$ contains the tangents of the canonical angles.
From an initial reading of the proof, it appears that the entries of $T$ ($\sigma_i$ in the paper) are the inner product of an eigenvector $v$ of $PP^*$ and a perpendicular vector from the subspace spanned by $\{v, P^*v\}$.

Can someone show me how this corresponds to the tangents of the canonical angles? Or, point me to a different approach to get this result.

Comment: If this isn't answered here within a day or two, you might want to look at Mathoverflow - a site focused on mathematical questions related to current research in mathematics.

Comment: That article costs €40 to read – you're going to have to summarize the proof.

Comment: Is it accessible here: https://eudml.org/doc/137431

Comment: Do you have a specific definition of the canonical angles between subspaces in mind?

Comment: I was thinking of the recursive definition of the angles between two spaces $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ and unit vectors $u,v$ using $$\cos\theta = \underset{u\in\mathcal{M},v\in\mathcal{N}}{\max} v^T u.$$ We find the next angle by restricting to vectors perpendicular to $u$ and $v$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These principal angles are invariant under unitary changes of basis. Thus, it suffices to show that this holds for the canonical-form projection $\tilde P = QPQ^*$.

The row-space $\mathcal V$ and column space $\mathcal W$ of $\tilde P$ are the column spaces of the matrices
$$
V = \pmatrix{I_p\\0} \quad W = \pmatrix{I_p\\T}
$$
respectively. Following your characterization of principal angles, we can proceed as follows. The first (largest) principal angle corresponds to the largest $\cos \theta$ for the angle obtained between a vector $w \in \mathcal W$ and the subspace $\mathcal V$. That is, it suffices to maximize $\frac{\|\mathrm{proj}_{\mathcal V}(w)\|}{\|w\|}$ for $w \in \mathcal W$. For $w = Wx$, $\operatorname{proj}_\mathcal V(w) = x$. Thus, our aim is to maximize $\frac{\|x\|}{\|Wx\|}$, which means that we must minimize $\frac{\|Wx\|}{\|x\|}$, which (noting that $W^*W$ is diagonal) occurs when $x = e_p = (0,\dots,0,1) \in \Bbb C^p$ (assuming that the $\sigma_j$ are in non-increasing order).

Thus, we conclude that the principal vectors associated with the principal angle are the final column of $V$, $v = e_p \in \Bbb C^n$ and the final column of $W$, $w = e_p + \sigma_p e_{n} \in \Bbb C^n$. Now, verify that the tangent of the angle between these vectors is $\sigma_n$.

Finding the next principal angle and components amounts to considering the same setup as the above, only with the final columns of $V$ and $W$ removed. By following the same process, we see that $\sigma_{n-1}$ is the principal angles between these smaller subspaces, and the pattern continues for the remaining $\sigma_j$.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think of working from the canonical form.